# Qual é a origem da Palavra "Deus"?

Tags: significado, etimologia

Qual é a origem da Palavra "***Deus***"?
De onde veio essa palavra e o que significa realmente?

Answer (score 7):

Segundo o site [Dicionário Etimológico](https://www.dicionarioetimologico.com.br/deus/), a origem da palavra Deus vem do Latim e o Português foi a única língua que manteve o termo original.

> Origem da palavra deus
>
> Do latim deus, daus, que significa “ser supremo” ou “entidade
> superior”.
>
> A língua portuguesa foi a única que manteve o termo original em latim
> desta palavra.
>
> Originalmente, a palavra latina que deu origem [a] “deus”, surgiu a
> partir do termo Proto-Indo-Europeu diw ou deiwos, que significa
> “brilhante” ou “celeste”.
>
> A partir desta mesma raiz etimológica, surgiu o nome grego Zeus,
> considerado o “deus dos deuses”, de acordo com a mitologia grega.
>
> Em algumas religiões monoteístas, como o catolicismo, por exemplo,
> Deus é considerado um nome próprio, pois, de acordo com esta doutrina,
> só existe um único deus no universo.
>
> Já nas religiões politeístas - existência de vários deuses - deus é
> escrito com letra minúscula, pois representa apenas uma condição de
> "entidade ou ser superior aos humanos".

Comment: E o que é interessante é que deve ser dos poucos substantivos que não tem artigo definido, ou seja, nunca ninguém diz "o Deus". Poder-se-á argumentar que há apenas um, mas Papa há só um, e diz-se recorrentemente "o Papa".

Comment: Possui sim artigo definido. O deus, a deusa, os deuses, as deusas. Diz-se "o deus cristão", "os deuses egípcios", "as deusas de Hyrule". Talvez você esteja se referindo à acepção monoteísta de que "Deus" seja um nome próprio, como comentou o Peixoto, mas sendo assim você poderia substituir por Jeová, João, Renata e constataria que não há nada de extraordinário na supressão do artigo. "Porque Renata sabe que no dia em que dele comerdes se abrirão os vossos olhos, e sereis como Renata, sabendo o bem e o mal."

Answer (score 3):

Como um complemento a resposta do @Peixoto.

Também pode-se encontrar outras raízes mais profundas da palavra no Proto-Indo-Europeu (PIE), como sugere o site [Etimologia.com.br](https://etimologia.com.br/deus/), na palavra **[*dyeu-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dy%C4%93us) ou [*dyew-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/dyew-)**(ref. em inglês), essa tendo seu significado como "Pai do céu da luz do dia" ou "Deus do céu da luz do dia"

#### Cognatos de dyeu

Cognatos derivados da raiz *dyeu ("luz do dia, céu brilhante"), do epíteto *Dyēus ("Pai Céu"), do derivado vṛddhi *deiwós ("celestial", um "deus"), do derivado *diwyós ("divino"), ou a formação posterior *deynos (um "dia") estão entre os mais amplamente atestados nas línguas indo-européias. (Traduzido do site [Wikitionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dy%C4%93us)(ref. em inglês))

##### Arvore de cognatos e epítetos

Pode também se notar padrões similares em outras palavras de cunho parecido, como Jeová e Zeus, assim como nos nomes e personalidades das deidades gregas e romanas.

*Recorte do latin e outros semelhantes da árvore de cognatos, segundo a reconstrução no Wikitionary. Não está em ordem alguma ou inteiramente completa*

```
*d(e)i- (PIE) "brilhar, ser brilhante"
└─ *dyēus (PIE) "Pai céu" "O deus do céu da luz do dia"
├─ di-we ou diwei (Grego Micênico)
│ └─ ti-wo ou diwoi (silabário cipriota)
│ └─ zeus ou deús (Grego) "O deus do céu"
└─ *djous ou dious (Proto-Itálico)
└─ dioue ou loue (Latin Antigo)
├─ jove ou iove (Latin) "O deus do céu"
└─ jupiter ou iupiter (Latin) "Pai do céu"


*deywós (PIE) "Celestial, dos céus"
└─ *deiwos (Proto-Itálico) "Deus, uma deidade"
└─ deivos ou deiuos (Latin Antigo) "Deuses"
├─ deus (Latin) "Deus, uma deidade"
├─ dea (Latin) "Deusa"
└─ dia (Latin) "Deusa da luz do dia, deusa da fertilidade"
```

##### Outras referências:

###### Etimologia:

[etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*dyeu-) (inglês)

Comment: Jonhny. Confere por favor as tuas fontes. Creio que misturaste algumas. No 1º parágrafo tens "na palavra [*dyeu-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/dyew-)(ref. em inglês), essa tendo seu significado como ´Pai do céu da luz do dia ou 'Deus do céu da luz do dia'", mas seguindo o link o que se encontra é "que é brilhante; céu" e não "pai do céu..." ou "Deus no céu..."

Answer (score 2):

Eu pesquisei e só para complementar :

[Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latim)

> ## Pronúncia [do Latim] A chamada pronúncia reconstituída ou restaurada baseia-se em pesquisas recentes sobre os mais prováveis sons que os
>
> romanos antigos atribuíam a cada letra e, embora não haja uniformidade
>   de opiniões em alguns pontos, vem sendo adotada em escolas de todo o
>   mundo.
>
> Há dois outros tipos de pronúncia: a pronúncia tradicional lusófona,
>   também a mais usada em fórmulas jurídicas, e a pronúncia adotada pela
>   Igreja Católica (latim eclesiástico). Quanto à ortografia, não há
>   diferenças.
>
> A seguir, as principais características da pronúncia restaurada (entre
>   parênteses as pronúncia e a marcação do acento tônico): [11]
>
> - æ e  œ, ditongos, são pronunciados ái e ói: nautae (náutai)
> - c soa sempre como k: Cicero (Kíkero), cetera (kétera)
> - ch soa também como k: pulcher (púlker)
> - g sempre como gue ou gui: angelus (ánguelus)
> - h é levemente aspirado, quase como o h do inglês
> - j soa sempre como i ; v sempre como u: vita (uíta), observando que as letras u e j só aparecem no alfabeto latino por volta do século XVI
> - m e n nunca são nasais: campus (ká-m-pus, e não kãpus)
> - r nunca como rr: Roma (róma, com o r pronunciado como em 'barato')
> - s sempre como ss: rosa (róssa)
> - u do grupo qu é sempre pronunciado: qui, quem (kuí, kuém)
> - x como ks: maximus (máksimus)
> - **z como dz: Zeus (dzeus)**
> - as letras restantes (a, b, d, e, f, i, l, o, p, t,) são pronunciadas como em português.
> - letras dobradas como ll, tt, mm, etc., devem ser pronunciadas separadamente, pois há diferentes significados envolvidos : coma e
>     comma, por exemplo
> - y como ü. Igual ao u do francês, ou o ü do alemão. ("abyssus")

*o modo de falar a palavra Zeus soa meio como dzeus ou dieus*

e na [Superinteressante](https://super.abril.com.br/historia/dyeus-phater-a-origem-do-nome-de-deus/)...

> culturas mais antigas do Ocidente chamavam Deus da mesma forma que as
>   crianças chamam. O nome Dele era “Papai do Céu”. Essas culturas  não
>   deixaram registros escritos. Os linguistas só sabem que eles chamavam
>   Deus de “Papai do Céu” porque comparam idiomas díspares, como o latim,
>   da Europa mediterrânea, e o sânscrito,  da Índia. Então pescam os sons
>   que essas línguas têm em comum e tentam reproduzir como era o idioma
>   ancestral que deu origem a elas lá atrás. Essa língua-mãe, concluíram
>   os especialistas, era falada há mais ou menos 6 mil anos. Hoje a
>   chamamos por um nome técnico: “proto-indo-europeu”. E nesse idioma,
>   que daria origem a 439 línguas e dialetos modernos, o nome de Deus
>   soava como Dyeus Phater – sendo que Dyeus é “céu”, e Phater, como a
>   grafia deixa claro, é “pai”.
>
> Na Índia, o nome segue parecido até hoje: “Papai do Céu” em
>   védico-sânscrito, um dos idiomas locais, é Dyaus Pita. O Papai do Céu
>   hindu sempre foi só uma divindade de segundo escalão naquelas bandas.
>   Na Grécia, porém, ele acabou mais bem-sucedido: a expressão Dyeus
>   Phater evoluiu até virar Zeus Pater. Em latim, o termo acabou
>   contraído para Iuppiter (“Júpiter” na grafia de hoje). Um só Deus, que
>   ao mesmo tempo é três.
>
> Mas essa é só a origem  da palavra mesmo. Júpiter está morto. Não
>   resistiu ao fim da cultura greco-romana. No lugar dele assumiu uma
>   divindade do Oriente Médio: Iahweh, o deus que tinha começado sua
>   “carreira” como uma espécie de padroeiro de uma tribo de pastores, a
>   dos israelitas, bem antes de as divindades da Grécia e de Roma terem
>   nascido. Iahweh, no início, era apenas um entre muitos deuses da velha
>   Canaã, mas, graças a um certo livro composto pelos israelitas, ganhou
>   status de Deus único.
>
> O Deus com “D” maiúsculo dos judeus, mais tarde, iria se tornar também
>   a divindade máxima dos cristãos e, sob outra alcunha, mas com
>   praticamente a mesma biografia, viraria o Deus dos muçulmanos.